# Workbook Open event and detecting this event in the Worksheet code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cut down on some duplicate coding in a .xlsm workbook. To do this, I have created a number of subs in the "Workbook Open" area that are now called from subs within Sheet 1. (Initially there were repeated code segments in both these). This all works fine!

### My question is this ...

Is it possible for code in Sheet 1 to know that it is being activated by the Workbook Open event?

For example, I have a combo box that is populated by the Workbook_open event which then fires off the sheet 1 Combo box "Change" event. However, I only want this change event to triggered by the user once the Workbook has been opened.

I've tried setting a global variable in Workbook Open but this only has scope within this event.

What would be the best workaround here?

Could I use a Workbook Module?
Should I write the variable to a cell in the worksheet and clear this out at the end of the event?
Some other solution?

Part of the Workbook Open code ..

```
Private Ws_Open As Boolean
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'
' set up drop down filter list
'
Range("A1").Select
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cmb_filter
    .Clear
    .AddItem "None"
    .AddItem "60% or less"
    .AddItem "70% or less"
    .AddItem "80% or less"
    .AddItem "90% or less"
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

Part of the Sheet 1 code ...

```
Private Sub Cmb_filter_Change()
 Dim intvalue As Integer
 Cmb_filter.BackColor = vbWhite
 Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Thisworkbook.clear_it"
..etc
```

Comment: Put the global variable in a normal code module, not a workbook module. Also, try passing variables, not using global variables.

Comment: Thanks @vacip. It's the passing of variables that is causing the problem. I've dealt a lot with UserForms in the past and know how to pass variables here, but am not clear on how this is achieved between the Workbook open event and a connected worksheet. Are there any articles taht deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to use a Public/Global variable to prevent the events from triggering

Place this in a **regular module** with the rest of your code :

```
Private Ws_Open As Boolean

Private Sub Cmb_filter_Change_Proc()
If Ws_Open Then Exit Sub
    Dim intvalue As Integer
    Cmb_filter.BackColor = vbWhite
    Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Thisworkbook.clear_it"
    '..etc
End Sub

Public Sub Wb_Open_Proc()
'
' set up drop down filter list
'
Ws_Open = True
Range("A1").Select
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cmb_filter
    .Clear
    .AddItem "None"
    .AddItem "60% or less"
    .AddItem "70% or less"
    .AddItem "80% or less"
    .AddItem "90% or less"
    .ListIndex = 0
End With

'rest of your code

Ws_Open = False
End Sub
```

And these in **`ThisWorbook` and `Sheet` modules** :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Wb_Open_Proc
End Sub

Private Sub Cmb_filter_Change()
    Call Cmb_filter_Change_Proc
End Sub
```

---

---

**Proposition that won't work for this specific case** (Control in a Worksheet), but will for most of the other events of Sheet, Workbook, ...

---

Simpler than detecting how the event is triggered, you can disable the events during your manipulation in the code with `Application.EnableEvents = False`

So your code will look like this :

```
Private Ws_Open As Boolean
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'
' set up drop down filter list
'
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("A1").Select
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cmb_filter
    .Clear
    .AddItem "None"
    .AddItem "60% or less"
    .AddItem "70% or less"
    .AddItem "80% or less"
    .AddItem "90% or less"
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents` won't affect the `Change` event of a control on a worksheet. You have to use your own variable.

Comment: @Rory : `EnableEvents` doesn't work on Controls? (I admit, I never use them as I find them dirty, I prefer a good UserForm!) Any other known limitations?

Comment: @R3uK. I can confirm that `EnableEvents=False` has no effect (in this particular situation). I meant to mention that I'd tried that in my initial posting. So how do I manage this with variables??

Comment: @R3uK It does work, but only on the events exposed by the container (GotFocus / LostFocus).

Comment: @MiguelH : I edited, let me know if it clear enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a Public variable. For example:
ThisWorkbook module:

```
Public Ws_Open As Boolean
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'
' set up drop down filter list
'
Range("A1").Select
ws_open = True
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cmb_filter
.List =  Array("None", "60% or less", "70% or less", "80% or less", "90% or less")
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
ws_Open = False
End Sub
```

then in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Cmb_filter_Change()
 Dim intvalue As Integer
 If ThisWorkbook.ws_Open then exit sub
 Cmb_filter.BackColor = vbWhite
 Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Thisworkbook.clear_it"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Found it. Seems that I do need a Module. I couldn't get the above solution to work. The Public declaration in the Workbook worked ok, but the Worksheet could not access the variable?

In the end I created Module1  with

```
Public Ws_Open As Boolean
```

This then made the variable accessible to all workbook objects.

Previously I had tried the Module solution, but with a Private variable declaration! Doh!

Comment: @R3uK. Just read your Module solution in more detail (answer 2). This looks neat! Is there any advantage of having code in a Module rather than in the Workbook Open Event or in the Worksheet (other than than the  availability of variables)? I've occasionally had problems with the Workbook Open event not firing correctly when the user has a lot of  workbooks open. I currently get around this with a "Refresh" button that the user clicks to manually fire the workbook open event.

Comment: Personally, I just prefer to proceed like this, I find it far easier to find what you are doing when you are working with Events (and UserForms), but I'm not sure there is a real advantage that would make it almost mandatory. So you keep all in your object module if you prefer! ;)